# Joomla VirtueMart - Get data from Database via PHP

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I am trying to setup a big website, and I've stumbled upon a technical issue. I have to create almost 2000 products and I need to use some automation in order to make this project viable.

So what I am trying to achieve is to be able to get info like product title, price etc from my database straight into the product description and meta description. This will save me probably hundreds of hours of work because will let me just copy paste one description instead of modifying all for each product.

Truth is that i am quite new to web development and my programming skills kinda limited, but i am quite sure that what i want to achieve is quite possible.

Joomla Version 3.7.3
Virtue Mart ver 3.0.19.8
PHP 5.4.31

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are Joomla extensions that can help with importing VirtueMart product details from a CSV file which will probably be quickest solution in your situation. For example:

- [CSVI Pro](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/migration-a-conversion/data-import-a-export/csvi-pro)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried CSVI pro and even though is a great tool, i find that my job is way too complicated to be performed with it since i have over 30 custom fields per product and I can't find a way to bypass that. What i am trying right now, is to export directly from Database to CSV and work with that.